# Using LastFM API to print out albums; call to a member function search() on a non-object error

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, last.fm

I am trying to implement the LastFM API to print out some albums using the package seen here:  https://github.com/matto1990/PHP-Last.fm-API

I have the following function in a controller:

```
public function album_print() {

        // Put the auth data into an array
        $authVars = array(
                'apiKey' => '*******************************',
                'secret' => '*******************************',
        );

        $config = array(
            'enabled' => true,
            'path' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/**********/*****************/app/lastfmapi/',
            'cache_length' => 1800
        );

        // Pass the array to the auth class to return a valid auth
        $auth = new lastfmApiAuth('getsession', $authVars);

        // Call for the album package class with auth data
        $apiClass = new lastfmApi();
        $albumClass = $apiClass->getPackage($auth, 'album', $config);

        // Setup the variables
        $methodVars = array(
        'album' => 'In Rainbows',
        'page' => 1,
        'limit' => 10
        );

        if ( $results = $albumClass->search($methodVars) ) {
        echo '<b>Data Returned</b>';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($results);
        echo '</pre>';
        }
        else {

        die('<b>Error '.$albumClass->error['code'].' - </b><i>'.$albumClass->error['desc'].'</i>');

        }

    }
```

I am trying to use the album.search function to find the album from a given input.  However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function search() on a non-object
```

Any idea why this would be happening?  I followed the example here: https://github.com/matto1990/PHP-Last.fm-API/blob/master/examples/album.search/index.php

more or less.  Thank you for your help.  (This is in a controller in Laravel 4)

Comment: what does var_dump($albumClass) output or var_dump($albumClass->error) give you?

Comment: var_dump($albumClass) gives me: bool(false)

var_dump($albumClass->error) gives me the error message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Then  $apiClass->getPackage( is returning false. Please consult the docs.

Comment: I looked at the getPackage function, and I see no reason why it would be returning false.  I am providing an api key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required an access token.  This why the object was not being read correctly.